# How to capture frame from the video view below android api level 14

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to capture an image from a live streaming URL but the `setDataSource(String uri, Map<String, String> headers)` method is only available on API 14+. How do I achieve this below 14 API?

Here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString(),new HashMap<String, String>());

            return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("test","error:"+ex);

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                retriever.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please Help me.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are the problem?....

Comment: Suraj. This is not a question.

Comment: this code is not support for api less than 14 this is the problem,thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Have you tried using: setDataSource(String path);? Perhaps you encountered this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794.

Comment: @william Seemann: i tried it using : setDataSource(String path); but it give me black screen.

Comment: thanks for your reply.for testing purpose i used this url:http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4

Comment: It works, see the screenshot attached in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri) {
    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());

        return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("test","error:"+ex);

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]